# cannot import name 'VectorStoreIndex' from 'llama_index'

Tags: llama-index

Unable to find the imports in LlamaIndex even after correct imports as of there latest docs

```
from llama_index.vector_stores.types import MetadataInfo, VectorStoreInfo
vector_store_info = VectorStoreInfo(
    content_info="brief biography of celebrities",
    metadata_info=[
        MetadataInfo(
            name="category",
            type="str",
            description=(
                "Category of the celebrity, one of [Sports, Entertainment,"
                " Business, Music]"
            ),
        ),
        MetadataInfo(
            name="country",
            type="str",
            description=(
                "Country of the celebrity, one of [United States, Barbados,"
                " Portugal]"
            ),
        ),
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the correct import is from:
`llama_index.core.vector_stores.types`

#### Why the additional `core`?

Just to clarify, especially for other people who run into `import` problems, the new versions of LlamaIndex `v0.10.0` and above have been refactored and there are breaking changes.

You can find the official migration guide here:
https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/getting_started/v0_10_0_migration/

#### `ServiceContext` is now `Settings`

It's also important to note that the `ServiceContext` has been replaced by `Settings`, and you can also find the migration guide here:
https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/module_guides/supporting_modules/service_context_migration/

So if you're on `v0.10.0` or above, make sure to go over the latest version of the docs to ensure you have the correct imports (https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/api_reference/).

To check the version installed on your machine, use: `pip show llama-index`